# sed replace string after matching and before

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file with some lines(basically MySQL query).

#### eg:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A576A2D299CFAF43CE15363F20BDD260FC1E9F77' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*CE15363F20BA576F43DD260FC1E9F77A2D299CFA';
```

I want to delete all the characters starting from `IDENTIFIED` and **before the 2nd single quote**.

#### Expected output:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user2'@'%';
```

Any AWK or SED commands?

Comment: Thank you for making the question clear. Can you also share your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

What you asked for (delete all the characters starting from IDENTIFIED and before the 2nd single quote):

```
$ sed "s/IDENTIFIED[^']*'[^']*//" file
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' ' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user2'@'%' ';
```

What will actually produce your expected output:

```
$ sed "s/ *IDENTIFIED.*'//" file
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user2'@'%';
```

Comment: Why not directly`sed "s/ IDENTIFIED[^']*'[^']*'//"`? That sort of combines your two sed snippets and will be easier for the OP to use.

Comment: @seshoumara because it's not necessary given the OPs input.